# ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 - line 1 column 2319 (char 4 - 2318)

Tags: python, json

I'd like to transform a string data inside a txt file, that have the same format of a json data, to a json data but I got this problem. I've tried to solve the problem in several ways but I was not successful. That's my code:

```py
import json

tweets_data = []

tweets_file = open('teste.txt', "r")

for line in tweets_file:
    dic_string = json.dumps(line)
    json_acceptable_string = dic_string.replace("'", '"')
    tweet = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
```

that's the error:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/cloves/Documentos/web_scraping/brincando_com_api_twitter/code_twitter/organize_data.py in <module>()
     11     dic_string = json.dumps(line)
     12     json_acceptable_string = dic_string.replace("'", '"')
---> 13     tweet = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
     14     tweets_data.append(tweet)
     15 

/home/cloves/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    337             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    338             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 339         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    340     if cls is None:
    341         cls = JSONDecoder

/home/cloves/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    365         end = _w(s, end).end()
    366         if end != len(s):
--> 367             raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
    368         return obj
    369 

ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 - line 1 column 2319 (char 4 - 2318)
```

The data is on postbin http://pastebin.com/UifenBxQ

Sample file (just one line):

```py
{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'#salina lawyers verifone ruby back office software', u'is_quote_status': False, u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 814580560538562560, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'timestamp_ms': u'1483046114464', u'entities': {u'user_mentions': [], u'symbols': [], u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [0, 7], u'text': u'salina'}], u'urls': []}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'id_str': u'814580560538562560', u'retweet_count': 0, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'favorited': False, u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': None, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 332149323, u'verified': False, u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/813776354625880064/Gx6wAXpp_normal.jpg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'followers_count': 13, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'332149323', u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'listed_count': 35}
```

Comment: can you post the input file as well? or put it in pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UifenBxQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this:

```
dic_string = json.dumps(line)
```

is useless, you already have a string, no need to serialize it again.

Then, the input has simple quotes and unicode prefixes, it is not `json` format, rather python dict format. Maybe the problem should be fixed on the opposite end.

Anyway, let's try to fix it from here. Your attempt at replacing quotes by double quotes is hazardous because you could also replace quotes in the strings.

Let's check the format:

```
{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'#salina lawyers verifone ruby back office software', ...
```

Basically each line is a valid python dictionary, so I'd parse each line using `ast.literal_eval` instead of `json`, and let's do it in a list comprehension for more efficiency.

```
import ast
with open('teste.txt', "r") as tweets_file:
    tweets_data = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in tweets_file]
```

now `tweets_data` is a list of dictionaries containing your data.

Note that `ast.literal_eval` can also de-serialize json data.